# How to reset a parachain with a new genesis on rococo?

Tags: parachain, rococo, cumulus

I want to reset a parachain currently active on the rococo testnet. There is documentation on how to [register a new parachain](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/rococo/). But what do I need to do in order to restart an existing parachain? I assume some extrinsic (but which) must be submitted as root with the new genesis and wasm blob.

I am not concerned with keeping messages queues but I want to keep the parachain id.

Comment: Please clarify: do you need to reset the parachain or you are ok with deregistering and then registering the parachain again? The former unlike the latter preserves the para id and message queues.

Comment: Clarification added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paras module exposes two dispatchables to control this:

- [`force_set_current_code`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/polkadot_runtime_parachains/paras/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#method.force_set_current_code)
- [`force_set_current_head`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/polkadot_runtime_parachains/paras/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#method.force_set_current_head)

Using the relay-chain governance, you can call those functions to resubmit the code and genesis head for your registered para.

Refer to this question to see what is head data and how to obtain it: [What is head data and how do I get it?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/396/what-is-head-data-and-how-do-i-get-it/397#397)

Currently there is no way to clear the message queues, if you care about that.