# How to run "paras" extrinsics on local setups

Tags: parachain, testing, motion

I would like to test a few scenarios about relaychain council / sudo can update our parachain code in case of emergency.

I searched over the web, and try to use "paras" module to do such, but always getting BadOrigin.

Following up @papyakin answer on this post: [How to reset a parachain with a new genesis on rococo?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/376/how-to-reset-a-parachain-with-a-new-genesis-on-rococo/382#382) it should work trought governance actions.

I tried on local setup kusama network and always get BadOrigin. The council is about 4 people and 4/4 ayes.
Am I missing anything?
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Update: tried also with parachain origin:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ***utility.dispatchAs(ParachainsOrigin)?*** You can use governance or sudo to call utility.dispatchAs

Comment: No luck, tried from sudo section and running it as regular extrinsic ( with sudo account )
Attached pics on description.